# How risky is a 2 hours layover in Paris Charles de Gaulle considering the COVID-19 situation?

Tags: france, layovers, covid-19

I shall be traveling to the US from India on 10th June this year for an internship, accompanied by my family. I booked a round-trip Delta flight recently; it has a ~2 hr layover at Paris Charles de Gaulle. I'm deliberating on whether to cancel my tickets and choose some other route. Currently, there seem to 334 COVID-19 cases in Île-de-France (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_outbreak_in_France#Statistics)) but that does not appear to be a *considerable* percentage considering the ~12 million population in the region.

I'm looking for some advice here, preferably from someone who has visited Charles de Gaulle recently or is well aware of the situation there. Obviously no one can accurately predict what the situation will be in June, but perhaps one can extrapolate a few things from the current scenario.

Comment: Situations can quickly change. Noone can predict what will happen. By June, if France can't contain the virus, flights will be cancelled.

Comment: Moreover, choosing another route today doesn't prevent that route to undergo virus by 10th June.

Comment: This is completely opinion based. There's no way to predict how things will be in June at all. Exponential growth can change things very quickly. Hold on to your tickets. If the situation gets worse then the airline will reroute or refund you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, assuming you are not a US citizen or permanent resident, or in a fairly small set of other aliens, you cannot enter the US within 14 days of being physically present in the Schengen area.  If that restriction is still in place on June 10th, you will have to cancel or re-route your flight.

But who knows: in three months' time, maybe the Schengen area restrictions will be lifted. 
 Maybe India will have millions of infections and be added to the restricted list.  It's impossible to say.

If I were you, I'd just keep my plans in place and adjust them as necessary closer to the actual trip, based on the public health measures in place at the time.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately my crystal ball isn't working today, but I will try to provide an answer anyway.

I don't know why you are worried about a 2-hour layover in a location in 3 months time, which currently has very few infections.
Shouldn't you be more concerned about spending 12+ hours in a thin metal tube within a few centimetres of hundreds of people?

Even if you did catch it, then the vast majority of people survive and are not badly affected and don't need hospital treatment of any kind.
And as of 11th March some 4,300 people have died of the illness.  Out of ~120,000 infections.  And I believe that every death was somebody which already had underlying heath conditions.
Source:  https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-death-toll/

Compared to 1.25 million people who died in road traffics accidents (2013 https://www.who.int/gho/road_safety/mortality/traffic_deaths_number/en/) then you should probably be more worried about taking a safe means of transport to/from the airport!

Comment: OP may not be worried for themselves, but for infecting other, more vulnerable people — and people who die in road traffic accidents don't all die at the same time potentially overwhelming the hospitals, they are relatively equally spread over the year which allows for good planning capability.

Comment: ^^While you have a point about OP being worried about others or the potential overloading of the health services, the answer makes the very valid point that OP is probably at a greater risk from Covid-19 being cooped up in a sealed metal tube with a bunch of strangers than walking around CDG airport for 3 hours.

Comment: "Very few infections" probably untrue (France already has 2,281). And the number will only grow, likely exponentially. But it is also likely that in 3 months it would be all over.

Answer (score 2):

Your additional risk in CDG is minuscule compared to the risk in the indian airport, the US airport, and the flight itself.
If the flight will be happening at all, and if you are even allowed to fly - which is both unclear today - your worries about some hours in CDG are unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can tell you what the situation is on June 10th. Coronavirus might be gone, or all flights from India might be cancelled, or all flights to France might be cancelled.

At the airport, you can reduce your risk: Stay away from people (5 meters), especially coughing people, don't touch anything, wash your hands after touching anything.